# Adroid kotilin worker get live data from database from different class, same package

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, worker

In my application I populate a database with some data.

In order to trigger periodic notifications, I set a worker to execute once per day. The condition to trigger the notification shall be checked inside the worker, so the UI can handle data change ad differe entry/exit points.

How can I pass the live data to the worker or tell the worker to get the live data?

My woker is in a separate class, I think I should pass the live data usine the WorkerParams but I am not sure on the kind of data thatI shall pass, and if I then need to cast it or whatever:

normally I would do:

```
    [...]
    workerData.putString(NOTIFICATION_ID,notificationId.toString() )
    workerData.putString("Operation", "Set")
    workerData.putString("Date2", date2)
    [...]
    val notificationWork = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NotificationWorker>(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setInputData(data)
                    .build()
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(notificationWork)
```

then I would unpack data in the NotificationWorker object:

```
class NotificationWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters): Worker(context, params) {
override fun doWork(): Result {
    val notificationId = inputData.getLong(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0).toInt()
    val operation= inputData.getLong("Operation", 0).toInt()
    [...]
    // do stuff here
    [...]
    return Result.success()
   }
}
```

my data is in the form:

```
LiveData<List<Entity>>
```

shall I use se a

```
workerData.putAll(myVar)
```

and in the worker

```
val notificationId = inputData.getAll(..)as  LiveData<List<Entity>>
```

I really have no idea on how to perform this task,

Any hint would be gladly appreciated

K.R.

Comment: If you are using room for saving data in local database then you can return livedata from room query and use it directly inside worker class i.e use query inside worker class.

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing a live data into the worker i suggest you make a `ViewModel` class and put your live data there, then inside your worker class create a viewModel instance and use that live data from inside the viewModel which is also the "best practices".
Hope it helps

Comment: Hello Yarin, 
Thanks, I'm trying with your answer and makes sense.
Now I have to unserstand how to istantiate it because looks like I am missing a point here:
Required:
ViewModelStoreOwner
Found:
NotificationWorker

Comment: to instantiate a viewmodel in your class :
`viewModel=ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory().create(YourViewModelClass::class.java)`

Comment: unfortunately I have no empty constructor for my view model.
Can I istantiate with 
var mealViewModel: MealViewModel =  MealViewModel(applicationContext as Application)
?

Comment: No, View Models dont have their own constructor simply because viewModel is supposed to be a singelton and have only 1 instance of it at any time. Therefore, you use the `ViewModelProvider` class as i mentioned and then you get the viewModel instance of the specific viewmodel class you write in the `create()` method